# CGAffineTransformMakeScale causes rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing this weird issue, where CGAffineTransformMakeScale is causing rotation. The name suggests that it should only cause scaling, but that's not the case.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.logoView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(6.0, 6.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                self.logoView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-6.0, -6.0);
             } completion:nil];
        }
    }];
```

I would assume that the view should scale 6x and scale back 6x. However, the second animation causes a 90-degree anti-clockwise rotation of the image! Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Use the relative scaling transform rather than making an absolute one. So:

`self.logoView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.logoView.transform,
  6, 6)`

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't be scaling to **CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-6.0,-6.0)** in order to reverse what you already did (unless thats what you want, but i doubt it)  but instead animate back to **CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0)**.  a shortcut is **CGAffineTransformIdentity** constant, which is an empty transform.  So change that last line in the completion block to

```
self.logoView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

to explain whats currently going on, by scaling to a negative value in both x and y axes you are turning the view 'inside out' in both dimensions at the same time